# Angular Universal Package not adding main.server.ts , tsconfig.server.json,server.js, app.server.module.ts files in Angular .NET core fresh project

Tags: server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular16, .net-core-angular

I was trying to install angular universal in my .NET 6 Angular Project as default in VS2022. However , as seen in the screenshot , the package is installed but missed all the files that needs to be generated like server files , config files . I  used 'ng add @nguniversal/express-engine' and only this package is installed as seen in the package.json no other files or changes is seen .
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^16.1.1"
I got this error in the vscode terminal .

[image]